# How can I put an input in the alert() box?

Tags: javascript, html, input, alert

I have a question that I want to put an input in an alert box. What thing I have to do to create this? To make it I've to put an another tag, attrib, special properities, etc...
Thanks.
I think could be like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>example</title>
</head>
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  alert("<input></input>");
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you need `prompt`: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can't put anything in an alert box. As the name indicates, it's an alert. You might be looking for a [prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) which has an input text field, or [confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) to get a true / false depending on user selection.

```js
let foo = prompt('Type here');
let bar = confirm('Confirm or deny');
console.log(foo, bar);
```

Answer (score 5):

window object comes with three methods for showing user dialog boxes

this methods will halt current executing program till user provide any response to this box

```
window.prompt(text, defaultText)
```

this will take value from user for further process

```
window.alert(message)
```

this will only alert user for his action.

```
window.confirm(message)
```

this will take user response in boolean form for further process

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
var resp = window.prompt("Your question")
```

window.prompt is a blocking method (like alert). The program execution will halt until the user enters a value.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `var value = prompt('Your Question');`